# How do I build boost examples with bjam?

Tags: c++, windows, boost, bjam

Boost library is full of examples and tests and I would like to build them using bjam if possible.

How do I build boost examples with bjam?

PS. I wasn't able to locate proper documentation for this option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the library. Most of them run the examples from the test directory. Others from the example directory.

Go to the lib test or example directory where there is a Jamfile and do just

```
bjam
```

Comment: This would require to copy bjam from boost root. is it possible to call bjam from there for *all* boost libraries?

Comment: Once you have installed bjam, you can call bjam from any directory with a Jamfile. There are others ways, but this is the easy way.

Comment: There's no standard way to build examples for all libraries. In fact, that does not seem too useful -- given that example is something you'd have to manually play with anyway. On Linux, typing `bjam libs/*/example` from the root *might* work.